# req.body is empty whith fetch request

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, fetch, body-parser

i'm trying to make a fetch request to my server.
but i keep getting an empty req.body.

client script:

```
  const form = document.getElementById('form1')

form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const formData = new FormData(form);
    const link = formData.get('link');
    var payload = {
        link
    };
    console.log(payload);

    const options = {
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify(payload),
        headers: {
            'content-type': 'application/json'
        }
    }
    console.log(options);

    fetch('/api/gtmetriks', options)
        .then(response => response.json()).then(result => console.log(result)).catch(err => console.log(err));
})
```

server code:

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors')
const app = express()
//cors
app.use(cors())

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));
// parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.post('/api/gtmetriks', (req, res) => {       
    console.log(req.body);     
})
```

so when i post the request i get in the console '{}'. 
but no errors in the clients browser.

Comment: Is the ` console.log(payload);` printing the correct data?

Comment: this is the output: `{method: "POST", body: "{"link":"tesla.com"}", headers: {…}}
body: "{"link":"tesla.com"}"
headers:
content-type: "application/json"
__proto__: Object
method: "POST"
__proto__: Object`

Comment: Can you add a `res.sendStatus(200);` to your server code under the `console.log()` and then send the request headers? Does the server logs show any errors?

Comment: app.post('/api/gtmetriks', (req, res) => {       
    res.send(req.body);     
}) what if you do this

Comment: It worked fine on my computer.

Comment: @NickB. i get this err: `SyntaxError: Unexpected token O in JSON at position 0
    at fetch.then.response` but to be clear, my problem is that the server doesn't even get the post data.

Comment: @Osama when i do your suggestion i get in the console `{}` but no errors. and that's without what @nickB suggested

Comment: Convert extended to false

Answer (score -1):

I think the problem is that you are using CORS but not specifying which URL to POST to. For example, your client is `http://localhost:3000` but your server is `http://localhost:3001`. You are sending the fetch to `http://localhost:3000/api/gtmetriks` instead of `http://localhost:3001/api/gtmetriks`.

If you change your fetch to:

```
fetch('[YOUR SERVER URL]/api/gtmetriks', options)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(result => console.log(result))
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
})
```

It should work.

EDIT #1:

This code worked for me using a React frontend (3000) and an Express backend (3001):

Client app.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class App extends Component {
  handleSubmit = () => {
    const payload = {
      link: 'http://tesla.com',
    };

    const options = {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify(payload),
      headers: {
        'content-type': 'application/json',
      },
    };

    fetch('http://localhost:3001/api/gtmetriks', options)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(result => console.log(result))
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          this.handleSubmit();
        }}>
        Click Me
      </button>
    );
  }
}
```

Server server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const logger = require('morgan');
const cors = require('cors');

const app = express();

//use cors to allow cross-origin resource sharing
app.use(
  cors()
);

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.post('/api/gtmetriks', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);
  res.sendStatus(200);
});

//start your server on port 3001
app.listen(3001, () => {
  console.log('Server Listening on port 3001');
});
```

Comment: Didn't work: `fetch('localhost:5000/api/gtmetriks', options) .then(response => response.json()) .then(result => console.log(result)) .catch(err => console.log(err));`

Comment: Check the edit. I added working code and verified the request was being sent.

Comment: can't i use them both on the same port?

Comment: No, you cannot. Both React and Node have to be run on separate ports because they are both separate servers. React is your frontend server and Node is your backend server.

Comment: i'm not using react. pages are being rendered with ejs. the thing is that if i do normal post method. thourgh `<form action="/api/gtmetriks" >` it works good.

Comment: Can you verify in the network tab of Chrome developer tools that the request is going out and edit your question with the headers? This is most likely something to do with the EJS code.

Comment: It has nothing to do with ejs, the request is sent succesfully. even with postman it doesn't work. but if i change content type to application/x-www-form-urlencoded the server logs `[Object: null prototype] { '{\n\t\'link\':\'hello\'\n}': '' }`.

Comment: Can you show us the request header? We have verified that the backend code is working. That would lead us to believe that the frontend code is causing the problem.

Comment: @MendiSterenfeld in your first comment here, you're leaving out the `http://`, which is rather important..

Comment: this is the request headers: `Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,nl;q=0.8,he;q=0.7
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 20
content-type: application/json
Cookie: _ga=GA1.1.885619274.1550959657; MCPopupClosed=yes; _gid=GA1.1.554615336.1551803477; 
Host: localhost:5000
Origin: http://localhost:5000
Referer: http://localhost:5000/api/gtmetriks
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.121 Safari/537.36
`